# Syntax error in setting the current directory of command prompt in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, syntax-error, command-prompt

I saved a python file to my desktop. In order to test it, I used the command prompt. However, my command prompt is located in

```
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories
```

To change the current directory, I wrote

```
cd C:\Users\Name\Desktop
```

in the command prompt. However, it keeps telling me that I have an "invalid syntax"

```
>>>cd C:\Users\Name\Desktop
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    cd C:\Users\Name\Desktop
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestion to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `>>>` prompt indicates you are already running python interpreter.

You need to enter that command from the shell prompt.

Press Ctrl-D to exit Python to the ordinary shell prompt and try again.

P.S: I'm not related to anyway with python Reference : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1558728

try this on **ms-dos**

```
cd\
cd C:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop
python filename.py
```

Comment: So I typed C:\Users\Name>Desktop (> is there from he start) but it's telling me that it can't recognize Desktop

Comment: where's your `.py` file located ?

Comment: It's located on my desktop